# m2e plugin in Eclipse crashing

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I've experiencing crashes on m2e Maven plugin for Eclipse (in STS) everytime it starts. This issue was treated in STS forum ([link here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/749864-sts-ggts-3-6-0-m1-released?view=thread)), but, in my case, it didn't seem that was another plugin to cause conflict. STS was working fine, but without any clue it starts to crash during STS initialization. It have happened once two weeks before, and I have managed it by updating STS to its latest version. But now I'm using the latest version!

In this moment, a ss command in Host OSGi Console shows:

```
570 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.5.0.20140605-2032
571 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.core_1.5.0.20140606-0033
572 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui_1.5.0.20140606-0033
573 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.discovery_1.5.0.20140606-0033
574 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.editor_1.5.0.20140606-0033
575 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml_1.5.0.20140606-0033
576 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.5.0.20140606-0033
                Fragments=577
577 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui_1.5.0.20140606-0033
                Master=576
578 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.launching_1.5.0.20140606-0033
579 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults_1.5.0.20140606-0033
580 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender_1.5.0.20140606-0033
                Master=5
581 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration_1.5.0.20140606-0033
582 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.5.0.20140605-2032
583 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.5.0.20140605-2032
584 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.5.0.20140605-2032
585 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit_1.5.0.20140606-0033
586 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core_1.5.0.20140606-0033
587 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui_1.5.0.20140606-0033
588 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring_1.5.0.20140606-0033
589 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.m2e.scm_1.5.0.20140606-0033
590 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp_1.1.0.20140611-1646
591 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs_1.1.0.20140611-1646
592 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa_1.1.0.e43-20140611-1648
593 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf_1.1.0.20140611-1646
594 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.overlay_1.1.0.20140611-1646
595 STARTING    org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.overlay.ui_1.1.0.20140611-1646
```

All Maven's dependencies for my project are disabled, and every import is broken in design time in Eclipse. Any idea on what is going wrong here and what would be a workaround? How do I uninstall m2e in order to reinstall it, if it is possible? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some details on what plugins you've installed into youe Eclipse/STS? Ideally you should be able to uninstall from About Spring Tool Suite (or About Eclipse) -> Installation Details -> Installed Software (tab). Uninstall is disabled however for M2E plugins though...

Comment: There's no other pluggins installed beyond those which came in STS release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a full reinstall of Spring Tool Suite. I do recommend to maintain original zip file of your STS version in order to do reinstall it at any given time, if needed. Very anoying crash, I hope Spring team pay attention and try to fix it in next release!

Comment: would you file an issue at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and provide some more details about the issue? Maybe crash or error log entries? or some steps/sample projects how to reproduce this? That would be awesome and help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with m2e ans finally had to give up. Eclipse also started to become very slow when the project started to become big. I finally rresorted to switch to the free version of intellij and I like it very much. But it requires some setup work and getting used to it.

Comment: Good tip. I had never heard about this alternative, but in this moment it would be impossible to me to change my IDE.